# long distanced server is taking too much time compared with my local server for getting the same response

Tags: java, protocols, network-protocols

I have created one web application. Now I'm testing performance. The distanced server is taking more time to respond.

**Example**

When I send request to my local serve it respond within 0.454 seconds. but When I send request to distanced server it is taking 22.930 seconds to respond.

Its difficult to find out the reason for this...

with advanced thanks,

-Ganesh-

Comment: Do servers have same configuration? May be this server is pretty slow/low memory and your app works much slower there.

Comment: The server configuration is higher compared with my local server. I think the distance may be reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps you to check first the tcp/ip network to see if the network is the bottleneck.

- Try with a ping or even better with a tracert command ( windows ).
  With the tracert you see each hup and the time that it takes for a
  packet to go there and back. it's a good way to see the delays.
- Maybe the remote server is slow or has limits.
- Try your code on another server, just to distinguish with less effort, that
  it has nothing to do with the server itself.

If this didn't help. then it is maybe necessary to go into the java code.

Comment: Thank you daniel I will let u know after tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely due to network interaction (assuming this is the only difference)

A remote server can have a latency of 25 - 250 ms and if you need to pass multiple requests to perform an action it can add up to minutes pretty quickly.  The same number of requests on a network with a latency of say 0.2 ms might not show a problem.